# Is Length of positive continuous function bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a positive continuous function on $[0,1]$. Set
>
> \begin{array} \\A=\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \end{array}
>
> prove that
>
> $$\sqrt{1+A^2}\leq\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f^2(x)} \, dx\leq1+A$$
> I can prove the second inequality, buy I stuck in the first one.
> Can I get a proof for this not geometrical?

Comment: Which inequality is the first, which is the second?

Comment: If you mean the length of the graph of $f$, it should be $f'(x)^2$, not $f(x)^2$. But then it's not true.

Comment: Formula for length should have the function differentiated.  And for the theorem to hold, derivative has to be continuous.

Comment: Are you familiar with Jensen Inequality  ?

Comment: @user251257 no need for  $f$ to be convex to apply Jensen inequality .

Comment: Hint: $g(t) = \sqrt{1+t^2}$ is convex and apply Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Added: OK, I now see the request was for a nongeometrical proof. I'll leave this up for a while anyway.

---

To show $\sqrt {1+A^2} \le \int_0^1 \sqrt {1+f(x)^2}\,dx,$ define $F(x) = \int_0^x f.$ Note the graph of $F(x)$ is a curve from $(0,0)$ to $(1,A).$ The length of this curve is

$$\tag 1\int_0^1\sqrt { 1 +F'(x)^2}\,dx = \int_0^1\sqrt { 1 +f(x)^2}\,dx.$$
But the straight line distance between these points is $\sqrt {1+A^2}.$ Since $(1)$ is at least the straight line distance, the inequality follows.